# Autodetect endpoint address to connect - WCF C#

Tags: c#, wcf

Simple story,
I made a server using WCF, now I want to move the server to a different location. When moved client applications needs to be reconfigure the service they are listening because the ip is not the same. Can you automate this, when the server is moved all applications listening to it will autodetect the new location and address of the server.

Comment: Are the clients and the server on the same LAN?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by moving the server to a different location. But if you just mean the server will have to run with a different IP address and the old server will no longer run, then DNS is the solution..why not just give the new server the same hostname?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use WCF 4 and [auto discovery feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx). Here is a nice [link](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/11/24/getting-started-with-wcf-discovery.aspx) that give you the first steps

Answer (score 0):

Use WCF 4 Discovery. 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx